# JMS Serialized add condition to relation in entity

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I use jms serialized and restbundle for json respone
and I have entity with relation

```
class Questions
{

    /**
 * @var ArrayCollection|Notes[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Notes", mappedBy="questions", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Annotation\Groups({
 *     "get_question", "get_questions"
 * })
 */
private $note;
```

and my action

```
        $context = SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks();
    if ($groups) {
        $context->setGroups(["get_questions"]);
    }

    if ($withEmptyField) {
        $context->setSerializeNull(true);
    }

    return View::create()
        ->setStatusCode(self::HTTP_STATUS_CODE_OK)
        ->setData($questions)
        ->setSerializationContext($context);
```

and everything ok, in response I have `note` key with `Notes` objects

```
      "note": [
    {
      "author": {
          "id": 17,
          "name": "qq"
      },
      "id": 4,
      "text": "aaawww"
    },
```

but I want add some condition for this, example I want `Notes` by author, example I want filter bu user authentication. I can added SerializesAccessor and add "getter", but I can create getter function only in entity, how can I get authentication user in entity... ? Or how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You should handle in a service where you inject the security as described here https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system

Comment: I create `serializer.post_serialize`, but how change data in `ObjectEvent $event` ?

Comment: I understood, coll

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I use jms serialized event. And After this event I could change `ArrayCollection` in my response by auth user condition

```
class SerializationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
private $tokenStorage;

private $user;

private $notesRepository;

public function __construct(
    TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
    NotesRepository $notesRepository
) {
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    $this->notesRepository = $notesRepository;
    $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
static public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize',
            'class' => Questions::class,
            'method' => 'onPreSerialize'
        )
    );
}

public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
{
    /** @var Questions $question */
    $question = $event->getObject();
    if ($this->user instanceof User) {
        $authorNotes = $this->notesRepository->findBy(['user' => $this->user, 'questions' => $question]);
        $question->setNoteCollection($authorNotes);
    }
}
}
```

and config

```
    app.listener.serializationlistener:
    class: "%app.serialization_listener.class%"
    arguments:
        - "@security.token_storage"
        - "@app.repository.notes"
    tags:
        - {name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber}
```

and set Collection

```
    /**
 * @param Notes[] $notes
 * @return $this
 */
public function setNoteCollection(array $notes)
{
    $this->getNote()->clear();
    foreach ($notes as $note) {
        $this->addNote($note);
    }

    return $this;
}
```